# Page jumps when carousel content changes it height/content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-carousel

I am facing an interesting behavior on my page when the boostrap carousel is wrapped and the wrapper is `position:absolute`... so when the page is a bit scrolled down and next `carousel-item` has a different `height` the page simply "jumps"...

My `home-hero-wrapper` is 100vh and the `carousel-home-wrapper` which wraps the carousel is positioned absolute at the bottom. Regardless the size of the `carousel-item` it will be positioned at the bottom of the `home-hero-wrapper`

**The Problem:**
All works fine until you scroll down the page a bit (The carousel must still on the viewport) and on the carousel transition the page simply "jumps"... However `home-hero-wrapper` does not change size and I can't figure why the sections are behaving like this...

What am I missing? Any tips?

The snippet below is reproducing the issue:

```css
.home-hero-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.carousel-home-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="home-hero-wrapper bg-info">
    <div class="hero-image" style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1024x800);">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-home-wrapper">
            <div 
              id="carousel_home" 
              class="carousel slide carousel-fade" 
              data-ride="carousel"
              data-interval="1000"
             >
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item bg-light active">
                        <h2>Content Shorter</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item p-3 bg-light">
                        <h2>Content Longer</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem rem earum temporibus perferendis corrupti minus harum, ex ipsam molestiae iste dicta voluptatum mollitia quia animi ut, soluta molestias natus ipsa.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- #carousel_home -->
        </div><!-- .carousel-home-wrapper -->
</div><!-- home-hero-wrapper -->
<div class="p-5 bg-warning">
  <h2>Scroll until here</h2>
  <h3>Make sure carousel still visible</h3>
  <p>Waiting until carousel transition... All sections will "jump"</p>
</div>
<div class="p-5">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem rem earum temporibus perferendis corrupti minus harum, ex ipsam molestiae iste dicta voluptatum mollitia quia animi ut, soluta molestias natus ipsa.
</div>
<div class="p-5">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem rem earum temporibus perferendis corrupti minus harum, ex ipsam molestiae iste dicta voluptatum mollitia quia animi ut, soluta molestias natus ipsa.
</div>
<div class="p-5 bg-danger">
  <h2>Make sure carousel still visible</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want carousel-item to be same height?

Comment: No, all the `carousel-item` height will be different

Comment: yes it is different, and what is your problem?

Comment: I've described in the question... Have you seem the code snippet? if you scroll down a little bit until the yellow section and also keep the carousel visible, when the carousel transition happen, the page jumps... thanks

Comment: yes it jumps because `carousel-item` height is not same that's the reason it jumps, If you have same height for `carousel-item` there won't be page jump.

Comment: That is the problem, and your solution do NOT solve the problem as in this case the `carousel-item` must be different... have you considered that the `home-hero-wrapper` is positioned `relative` and is bigger than the `carousel` which is `absolute` positioned?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208466/discussion-between-caiovisk-and-sanoj-lawrence).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, to do so first add the class **`p-3`** to both **`carousel-item`** **`<div>`** or remove from both.

Secondly, remove all the classes from the **`<div>`** with id **`#carousel_home`**.

---

Also, add this CSS:

```
.carousel-item{
  height: 130px;
}
```

---

Now if the ***`text`*** inside the ***`carousel-item`*** will be shorter than the ***`full width`*** of the page then it will take only that amount of ***`width`*** taken by the ***`text`***.

And if the ***`text`*** inside the ***`carousel-item`*** will be longer than the ***`width`*** of the page then the ***`text`*** will go to the next line.

Plus it will be anchored with the ***`class` `home-hero-wrapper`*** ant the ***`bottom`*** of the page. Take a look at the live code with the ***`link`*** below (NEW)

---

> ***See the live code here (NEW): https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/QWbpvMW***

---

*See the live code here (OLD): https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/zYGNyxg*

---

Comment: Thanks Mate, but it does not work ... Your solution is just limiting the size of the `carousel-item` ... and using ` width: fit-content` hides the content inside `carousel-item`  if it is narrow... The `carousel-item` must change its height and must be 'anchored' to the bottom of the `home-hero-wrapper`

Comment: Thanks for that, but still "jumping".. if you scroll the page until you see the Yellow section, you will se that the section jumps between the carousel transitions...

Comment: ReEdited the answer, now it is not jumping. We need to give a fixed height to the ***`class` `carousel-item`***. Like: `.carousel-item{ height: 130px; }`.

Comment: Indeed if we fix the `height` it doesn't jump, but that is my issue, the height of `carousel-item` cannot be fixed... It has different height on each carousel item

Comment: If the `height` is not `fixed` then it is obvious that item with `less content` will move up and item with `more/large content` will move down. Other than that you can try `fixing` a word limit to `display` with `javascript` and add a `read more button` to read further.

Comment: `home-hero-wrapper` has fixed height and `position: relative`, `carousel-home-wrapper` which is inside home-hero-wrapper has `position: absolute`, no matter of the size of the carousel, NO content below `home-hero-wrapper` should move/jump, but it is moving/jumping...